# module 'pygmaps' has no attribute 'maps'

Tags: python, pygmaps

```
pickup_map = pygmaps.maps(40.752928, -73.881528, 12)
dropoff_map = pygmaps.maps(40.752928, -73.881528, 12)
```

> I am getting this error:- module 'pygmaps' has no attribute 'maps'

Comment: Check if the required libraries are available and not corrupted

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your code should be like the following:

```
import pygmaps
pickup_map = pygmaps.pygmaps(40.752928, -73.881528, 12)
dropoff_map = pygmaps.pygmaps(40.752928, -73.881528, 12)
```

Comment: Yes, but when i am running this it shows pymaps has no attribute maps.

Comment: check if pygmaps is installed `print(pygmaps.__version__)`.